Quantikz: How to remove wire beside vertical dots?
How to remove wire beside vertical dots?
\def\myvdots{\ \vdots\ }
\begin{align} 
\begin{quantikz}[row sep = 0.7em, thin linesm ]
    \lstick{}  & \gate{H} & \gate{X} & \ctrl{2} & \gate{X} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
    \lstick{}  & \gate{H} & \gate{X} & \ctrl{1} & \gate{X} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
    \lstick{}  & \myvdots & \myvdots & \myvdots  & \myvdots  & \myvdots &\qw \\
    \lstick{}  & \gate{H} & \gate{X} & \gate{Z} & \gate{X} & \gate{H} & \qw 
\end{quantikz}
\end{align}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for answering. I'll make sure to provide more complete and understandable code in the future.

You're welcome! And you can still edit this question in order to make it compilable. A compilable example will help future users determine if they are in fact in the same situation as you or if their problem might be different.

You could use \setwiretype{n} to change the wire type to none:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\def\myvdots{\ \vdots\ }
\begin{align} 
\begin{quantikz}[row sep = 0.7em, thin lines]
    \lstick{}  & \gate{H} & \gate{X} & \ctrl{2} & \gate{X} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
    \lstick{}  & \gate{H} & \gate{X} & \ctrl{1} & \gate{X} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
   \setwiretype{n} \lstick{}  & \myvdots & \myvdots & \myvdots  & \myvdots  & \myvdots & \\
    \lstick{}  & \gate{H} & \gate{X} & \gate{Z} & \gate{X} & \gate{H} & \qw 
\end{quantikz}
\end{align}


\end{document}


